# Looking for an IBM multimedia demo from the 80s/90s about "Ulysses"

Tags: ibm, text, identify-this-software, multimedia

I am trying to identify / find an online copy of a multimedia technology demonstration video. Timeframe: late 1980s / early 90s? Source: IBM. Format: VHS.

The content of this video was a computer program with a voice recording of either the original Greek [epic of Ulysses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey) or maybe James Joyce's [book of the same title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_(novel)). The video showed details of how the program would display the text simultaneously with the reading, and had some annotations and other features.

I think the point of it was to show off the multimedia capabilities they had developed by using a real application of the book I mentioned; it may have been touting it for educational purposes.  Today this kind of technology it obviously taken for granted but at the time it was innovative and impressive!

All these recollections are probably subject to error but that's what I remember...

I've done some searching but can't find any reference to it - but I bet its out there somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Was it [Ulysses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJGhxVOR4gA) ([alt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0qGIpBsYg4)), Tennyson's poem from *[Illuminated books and manuscripts](https://www.worldcat.org/title/illuminated-books-and-manuscripts/oclc/32056663)* (pub. IBM Educational Systems, 1992)?

[image]

Comment: I've come back to this a few times now and II'm not certain its a match though it is similar. Some aspects of this seem like what I remember, but other details are quite different. I don't recall the guy speaking, and although the poem seems right all the background images & video edited in with it are totally unfamiliar. What I had seen was much drier. I wonder if IBM had several versions of this or re-used some elements in more than one product / demo.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you are looking for
http://entersection.com/posts/290-alfred-tennyson-on-the-guides-of-force-in-nature-ulysses

Here is a better version of the same
https://youtu.be/c0qGIpBsYg4

Comment: While this might be relevant, it would help to format it into a full answer. So far it's a link only item, isn't it?

Comment: That link has the same video embedded as the other answer